# How to go down N lines in vim without a previous buffer

Tags: vim

To go down four lines in vim where there are pre-existing lines I can do `4j`.

Is there a way to do this when, for example, opening a new file?

Answer (score 1):

You can run any command by doing `:e +command ~/somepath/somefile` for your example, that'd be `:e +4j ~/somepath/somefile`

Comment: I mean in the same file, without opening a new file.

Comment: @David542 you wrote in your question: "Is there a way to do this when, for example, opening a new file?" what do you want exactly?